# Validate_conversion function in a JOIN ON clause - ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I populate them with some data:

```
create table qz_products (
   id    integer primary key
 , name  varchar2(20) not null unique
);

create table qz_wishlist (
   user_name   varchar2(10) not null
 , id_or_name  varchar2(20) not null
);

insert into qz_products values (1042, 'Bowling ball' );
insert into qz_products values (1088, 'Bottle opener');
insert into qz_products values (2021, 'Bikini top'   );
insert into qz_products values (2069, 'Beach parasol');

insert into qz_wishlist values ('Bob'  ,'1042');
insert into qz_wishlist values ('Bob'  ,'Bottle opener');
insert into qz_wishlist values ('Betty','Bikini top');
insert into qz_wishlist values ('Betty','2069');
```

I want to join these tables on a specific condition: When field id_or_name is a number datatype, I would like to join with id field from qz_products table. Otherwise I would like to join using name field from qz_products table, so the output should be as follows:

```
USER_NAME          ID NAME
---------- ---------- --------------------
Betty            2021 Bikini top
Betty            2069 Beach parasol
Bob              1042 Bowling ball
Bob              1088 Bottle opener
```

I came up with an idea using VALIDATE_CONVERSION function. This is my query:

```
select w.user_name, p.id, p.name
from qz_wishlist w inner join qz_products p
on w.id_or_name = (case when validate_conversion(w.id_or_name as number) = 1 then p.id
                    else p.name end);
```

And I've got an error there:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
```

I know, what does this error mean, but I'm not sure, why I have it.
What did I miss there? 
Best regards.

Comment: The case expression's different result values must have compatible data types. Number and char aren't.

Comment: `then cast(p.id as char(11))...`

Comment: @jarlh Damn, you are right. Im so silly. That is obvious, but i still forgot about that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

All branches of `case` must return the same datatype, so your approach won't work: use `or` conditions instead.

Also, I would recommend using `to_number()` with the `on conversion error` option instead of `validate_conversion()`. This validates and converts on the fly. If the value cannot be converted, we can make `to_number()` return `null`, so it cannot match on `p.id`.

```
select w.user_name, p.id, p.name
from qz_wishlist w inner join qz_products p
on 
    to_number(w.id_or_name default null on conversion error) = p.id
    or w.id_or_name = p.name
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c93f823eac9fdcd2827cc75b9b9a13b8)**:

```
USER_NAME |   ID | NAME         
:-------- | ---: | :------------
Bob       | 1042 | Bowling ball 
Bob       | 1088 | Bottle opener
Betty     | 2021 | Bikini top   
Betty     | 2069 | Beach parasol
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just wanted to know, why validate_conversion function was wrong. However i made a silly mistake in case expression, so now it is working. Thank you  one more time :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @jarlh for showing the problem. I feel so silly right now haha. 
The problem was with case expression datatypes.
However, when i used

```
then cast(p.id as char(11))
```

I' ve got:

```
USER_NAME   ID  NAME
Bob        1088 Bottle opener
Betty      2021 Bikini top
```

But that was straightforward - datatypes didnt qute exactly match.
I used

```
then cast(p.id as varchar2(11))
```

Which solved my problem. Thank you!